# Border-radius breaks in the corners

Tags: html, css

I designed a contentbox for a website and on the desktop it looked good. But now I want to put it on the mobile.
You can see a example with only relevant html+css here http://pastehtml.com/view/bze2phhwn.html
On my smartphone, ive seen that the border-radius breaks(it displays the background color instead of the border color) in the rounded corners for 1-3px and you can see this effect also on the browser if you zoom in a little bit. Its weird, because if you zoom a little bit  out and in, you`ll see that this effect isnt always there. So I tought that it isnt my bad html+css.
What might be the problem?

Comment: What is your "smartphone"? It works fine on iPad, so I would think it will also be ok on an iPhone.

Comment: I have a samsung galaxy 3(240x400px,yes its shit), that means android. Did you try zooming?

Comment: I did try zooming. I don't have any Android devices to test on, sorry.

Comment: As i said, you can also test it in a browser, for example firefox and opera breaked it on my pc.

Comment: How about using box-shadow to emulate the border?

Comment: Can you post an example code?

Comment: FF and Opera looked fine to me... maybe I did't get your question. You're going to see the background color in the top left/right corners unless you remove the rounded corners or change your box-shadow code (so that the box shadow appears in other places besides the bottom of the box).

Comment: Pls look again at the bottom left corner. It has a red border, so now zoom in and always look at the corner. Youll see now that there are 2 white lines in the red border.<br>Sorry if it was not understandable.

Comment: Just recreated your code here http://jsfiddle.net/F3fDd/ - to actually see these two lines

Comment: Updated your code to minimum - http://jsfiddle.net/F3fDd/1/ - this DOES look like a bug!

Comment: @Radio: You did not need to ask [a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774506/border-radius-causes-white-lines-when-applied-to-individual-corners) if you were already working on this one.

Comment: @BoltClock: This question didn't get enough of attention to submit a bug to Mozilla! 49+15 views would make it a better view for a professionals to judge whether it's a bug or just a false panic. There is nothing wrong to create a separate (direct) question (to make sure) that it's good enough to submit to Mozilla directly... Please don't act bureaucratic way to solve a simple bug. You are making it way too political... If you got enough of power - it does not mean you have to use it to prove your status.

Comment: @BoltClock: This question wasn't clear enough to prove the BUG in direct way, that's why I created another one AND explained clear direct view of a bug. You made a big mistake closing a separate question - because Google wouldn't index that to get to a proper solution... Everything was done on purpose without duplicating an actual issue.

Comment: @Radio: Google does index questions closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Submitted to Mozilla:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758958

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774506/border-radius-causes-white-lines-when-applied-to-individual-corners/10774635#10774635

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug as well, but I found a fix... err maybe it would be considered a hack. Here is an image of my issue:

http://i909.photobucket.com/albums/ac298/roboyak/missingBorder_zpsbhftdfmd.png

So my story is that I was getting a reset.css style sheet imposed on me from the parent web page. The td element was getting the following style from that css sheet:

```
table tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Long ago when I started the project I overrode this style by stating the following rule in my sheet:

```
table tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

In trying to solve my problem I noticed that the border-bottom rule was showing up as "medium none" instead of none. I added the following code, and the border was no longer broken.

```
 table tbody tr td {
     border-bottom: none none;
 }
```

Essentially this breaks the rule so the border comes back again on all td's which is not what I want, but I think that this may give some insight into what is happening.